# SVG filter saturation on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I want to increase the saturation of an image, so I use this css:

```
-webkit-filter: saturate(125%);
```

It's working on Chrome, but not on Firefox 33 and older I think.
After searching on Google, I found this svg filter:

```
filter: url(resources.svg#filter-saturate);
```

Here is the resources.svg:

```
<svg>
    <filter id="filter-saturate">
          <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="1"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Now it's working on Firefox too, but the value of saturation must be from 0 to 1 (ex 0.25, 0.75, ...)

How can I increase to 1.25, like 125% on Chrome or any other solution to do that?

Comment: I would suggest use only `svg` filter to get the same result on all browsers. [Check out this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvk7tu8q/). `svg` filter on first image and CSS filter on second.

Comment: The restriction in saturation in Firefox to <= 1 was removed in Firefox 17 by https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826114 the patch includes a regression test so its unlikely this feature has been subsequently broken. Do you have a complete testcase as a jsfiddle that shows otherwise.

Comment: This works correctly in Firefox 34/windows (current). You might be using a very old version of FF.